# where to find and download stock android firmware for flashing and rooting phones?

Tags: rooting, custom-roms, stock-rom

i am new to this and am trying to learn about rooting and flashing customs roms. i am using a dell latitude E5450 runnig windows 11 pro insider preview. with 16gb ram i have multiple old phones rangeing from LGs to motorolas even have an coolpad phone.also have an galaxy watch 4 44mm that i bricked i cannot find firmware for it anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Please take a look at [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/44325). However, there's never a guarantee that there's firmware for every device.